# Passing arguments from child component React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to pass argument from child component to parent. P.S. Snippet below doesn't work if somebody fix this, it would be really great.

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {

  suggestionClick(id) {
    console.log(this.props, id); // {props Object} , undefined
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <ChildComponent click={this.suggestionClick.bind(this)} />
    );
  }
}


const ChildComponent = ({ click }) => (
  <SubChildComponent id="1" click={() => click()} />
);

const SubChildComponent = ({ click, id }) => (
  <div className="subsubcomponent" click={() => click(id)} />
);



ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: @Chris )) old logo of vk.com - russian duplicate of fb.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Don't use divs to trigger clicks. The right way is using a **button** for example
2. The right function handler is **onClick** not just click

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {

  suggestionClick(id) {
    alert(id);
    console.log(this.props, id); // {props Object} , undefined
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <ChildComponent click={this.suggestionClick.bind(this)} />
    );
  }
}


const ChildComponent = ({ click }) => (
  <SubChildComponent id="1" click={click} />
);

const SubChildComponent = ({ click, id }) => (
  <button className="subsubcomponent" onClick={() => click(id)}>click me</button>
);



ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are not passing the value from ChildComponent to parent component, here:

```
<SubChildComponent id="1" click={() => click()} />
```

Use this:

```
<SubChildComponent id="1" click={(id) => click(id)} />
```

Or Simply:

```
<SubChildComponent id="1" click={click} />
```

Another change is replace click with onClick inside SubChildComponent.

Working Code:

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {

  suggestionClick(id) {
    console.log(this.props, id); // {props Object} , undefined
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <ChildComponent click={this.suggestionClick.bind(this)} />
    );
  }
}


const ChildComponent = ({ click }) => (
  <SubChildComponent id="1" click={(id) => click(id)} />
);

const SubChildComponent = ({ click, id }) => (
  <div className="subsubcomponent" onClick={() => click(id)}>Click</div>
);



ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />,
  document.body
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In `ChildComponent`, just pass the `click` property directly to the `SubChildComponent`:

```
const ChildComponent = ({ click }) => (
  <SubChildComponent id="1" click={click} />
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **es6 arrow function** in your parent component, therefore no need to bind this to this function explicitly.

However when we call this function from child along with id to be passed to it, we bind this for passing the id value. Below is the modified code for reference. Hope this helps.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {

  // make this function as arrow function
  suggestionClick = (id) => {
    console.log(this.props, id); // {props Object} , id
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <ChildComponent click={this.suggestionClick} />
    );
  }
}


const ChildComponent = (props) => (
  <SubChildComponent id="1" click={props.click} />
);

const SubChildComponent = (props) => (
  <div className="subsubcomponent" onClick={props.click.bind(this, props.id)} />
);



ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```